# onClick activating every other onClick events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick, modal-dialog

I'm having an issue where I have multiple progress bar with onClick event created but when I click on the progress bar, every other progress bar's onClick event is activated.

I have a for loop that pushes multiple `<td>` with a progress bar in it to be rendered.

What I want to achieve is when the user clicks on each Progress Bar, different details appear on the Modal depending on which Progress Bar they click on.

I am using [react-overlays](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/react-overlays/#modals) modal.

[Picture of all the div showing up hidden after clicking on the Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyXvE.jpg)

Thank You for helping!

Code:

```
getInitialState: function(){
   return { showModal: false };
},

close(){
  this.setState({ showModal: false });
},

open(){
  this.setState({ showModal: true });
},


for loop(
  bodyRows[cellIndex].push(
      <td id="tableBody">
        <div className="progress" role="progressbar" id="progressBarStyle" onClick={this.open}>
          <Modal
            aria-labelledby='modal-label'
            style={modalStyle}
            backdropStyle={backdropStyle}
            show={this.state.showModal}
            onHide={this.close}
            keyboard={true}
          >
            <div style={dialogStyle()} >
                Hello
            </div>
          </Modal>
          <div className="progress-meter"  data-values={this.calculatePercent(value)}>
            {Math.floor(this.calculatePercent(value)) + '%'}
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
  )
)
```

Comment: I guess that you could pass a property or something to identify the particular click.  onClick={() => this.open('progressBar1')}

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you are controlling all the progress by a single state variable, instead of using a single state variable, use an array, Use these methods:

```
getInitialState: function(){
   return { showModal: [] };
},
```

Pass the index of each Item:

```
onClick = {this.open(index)}

onHide = {this.close(index)}

show = {this.state.showModal[index] || false}
```

Use the index to update specific item:

```
open(index){
  let showModal = this.state.showModal.slice();
  showModal[index] = true;
  this.setState({ showModal});
},

close(index){
  let showModal = this.state.showModal.slice();
  showModal[index] = false;
  this.setState({ showModal});
},
```

Comment: Sorry I was at lunch, but I figured out that if I leave the <Modal> out of the loop and then call it when the user clicks on the Progress bar, I can pass values into the Modal depending on which Progress Bar was clicked and display the details.

Comment: And somehow I can't mention your name with @.. Mayank Shukla

Comment: @VincentGoh ya you can do that, that will be more easy and simple :)